# vue-test-utils - Memory Leak with shallowMount / mount

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

#### Subject of the issue

Seeing a 2MB heap size increase after each test using shallowMount / mount.

#### Steps to reproduce

Run this command with the below setup:
`./node_modules/.bin/jest -- "DummyTest-test.js"`

- Vue Version 2.7.10
- Vue Test Utils Version 1.3.3
- Jest Version 29.0.3
- Node Version 14.20.0
- vue/vue2-jest Version 28.1.0

DummyTest-test.js

```
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import DummyComponent from "../DummyComponent.vue";

let iterations = [...Array(9999).keys()];
let wrapper;
let heap;

afterAll(() => {
  iterations = null;
});

afterEach(() => {
  wrapper.destroy();
  wrapper = null;
  heap = null;
});

it.each(iterations)(`Test`, () => {
  wrapper = shallowMount(DummyComponent);
  heap = (process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2);
  console.log(`Heap Size: ${heap} MB`);
  expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

DummyComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "DummyComponent",
};
</script>
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue2-jest",
  },
};
```

#### Expected behavior

Heap Size should remain consistent after each iteration of the test.

#### Actual behavior

Seeing a 2MB memory leak.
0.2MB of the leak looks to be coming from the usage of console.log, but the rest of the leak is coming from the mounting step.

#### Attempted Solutions

I have posted this same question on the [GitHub Issues page](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/2041).

Changing node versions (12, 16, 18) did not resolve the issue.

This is a Vue 2 project, so I cannot use vue-test-utils v2. However, I did a brief test on Vue 3 with Vue Test Utils v2, and it looked the issue was still present.

Looking for help on what to try next, or if others are experiencing the same issue.

I did see [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224101/any-way-to-avoid-memory-leaks-with-shallowmount-in-vue-test-utils) post from 4 years ago, but I am using `wrapper.destroy()` and `wrapper = null` after each test and the issue is still present.

To prevent CI from grinding to a halt, I'm using the [workerIdleMemoryLimit](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration/#workeridlememorylimit-numberstring) option from the latest version of Jest as a band-aid.

Comment: Try with `--runInBand`

Comment: @AndreyNelubin The --runInBand option made no difference in resulting heap size.

Comment: Does `enableAutoDestroy` help?

Comment: @AndreyNelubin No, enableAutoDestroy afterEach is not making a difference in heap size.

Comment: I just tested it. I think there is a deal with jest itself rather than vue or vue-test utils. Just try to remove the line with mounting. I left only two lines (console.log and expect) and the result is the same

Comment: @AndreyNelubin If I run the test without the mounting step, Heap Size goes down to ~170MB. If I leave the mounting step in, the heap size is ~1300MB. So, it looks like there is a big leak with vue-test-utils mounting step. (both mount and shallowMount have this problem).

If I also remove the console.log, heap size goes down to ~120MB. I'm not concerned about the console.log though, because that ordinarily would not be in a test.